# Determine hours using date and time fields

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, datefield, timefield

I have separate date and time fields for an event and the data entry of that event. How do I determine the hours between the event and the data entry?

The time field is a string in standard time which I converted to a military time time field using a formula.

date is written in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and time is in standard time `hh:mm am/pm` which I've converted to `HH:MM` military time.

If an event happened at 12:10 pm on 12/3/2016 but it was entered at 1:25 pm on 12/5/2016, I want to see `49 Hours and 15 Minutes` in my final field

Comment: can you show how your database format looks like and how you need in report

Answer (score 0):

`DateDiff` is just what you need. Something like:

```
DateDiff("h", DateTime({StartDate},{StartTime}), DateTime({EndDate},{EndTime}))
  & " Hours and " &
DateDiff("n", DateTime({StartDate},{StartTime}), DateTime({EndDate},{EndTime})) Mod 60
  & " Minutes"
```

This will retrieve the difference between your two dateTimes twice - Once in hours, once in minutes. Perform `Mod 60` on the minutes section to get only the remainder minutes after subtracting 60 minutes for each hour.

Comment: How do I combine the date and time fields prior to that?

Comment: `datetime({YourDateHere},{YourTimeHere})` (I've added it into my answer)

Comment: That works. Thanks!. One last question: It has a " - " before each figure. How do I eliminate that?

Comment: Sorry, it's only working to a point. If I had an event time of 11:30 am on 12/3/2015 and then a data entry time of 11:25 am on 12/5/2015 I should see a result of 47 hours and 55 minutes instead I get 48 hours and 55 minutes

Comment: @isoman4not5 If you're still getting negative values try swapping the end and start values. Or adding an absolute value function. ...As for the extra hour, I'd try testing it out with some dummy dates to see if it's always 1 extra hour. If that's the case, just subtract 1 from the hour count.

Comment: It's whenever the data entry time and the event time happened in the same hour but the event time came later than the data entry time relative to the respective day

Comment: @isoman4not5 - If I were you, I'd add Boolean logic to the formula to express what you just said. Here's a hint: You can determine which date came first by comparing them with `<` or `>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125207/discussion-between-isoman4not5-and-4444).

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I was about to make it overly complicated and try to compare characters in the strings